Find element in HTML text - Selenium Python
I'm trying to find elements by plain or innerHTML text:
newresults = driver.find_elements("xpath","//*[@class='card is-category-product']")    
for result in newresults:
    htmlEl = result.get_attribute('innerHTML')

So basically I want to search within my htmlEl variable
htmlEl returns each block as so:
<figure class="card-figure card-link">
    <picture class="card-picture ratio ratio-4x3">
        <source srcset="url-to-image">
        <source srcset="url-to-image"> <img src="url-to-image" class="card-img object-fit-contain is-contain" loading="lazy" alt="image-alt"> </picture>
    <figcaption class="card-caption">
        <h3 class="mb-0">TITLE OF CARD</h3>
        <p class="small">Random text</p>
    </figcaption>
    <a href="/random-url" class="card-link-overlay" title="TITLE" aria-label="title"></a>
</figure>

So for examplem I want to find the H3 element with class "mb-0" that should return - TITLE OF CARD. I've tried
foundname = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h3[@class='mb-0']")

but obviously this searches in my original URL specified and not in my htmlEl variable.

htmlEl is just a plain text string.  You can use .find and regex things to search it, or you can refine your xpath so it only returns the element you want.

You don't want to search the 'innerHTML' of an element because that returns the actual HTML as text as it's in the DOM on the page. That would mean you'd need to parse the HTML, etc. Selenium can handle this scenario more easily.
What you need is to chain .find_element() calls, e.g.
newresults = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='card is-category-product']")    
for result in newresults:
    htmlEl = result.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//h3[@class='mb-0']")
             ^^^^^^ we start from result

Because we are chaining .find_element() calls and are using XPath, you need to add a . (dot) at the start of the inner XPath
.//h3[@class='mb-0']
^ add a dot here

to indicate that you want to search from the element result.
NOTE: If you are using any other locator type, e.g. CSS selectors, ID, etc. you don't need to add this dot. For example, the same code using CSS selectors would be
newresults = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".card.is-category-product")    
for result in newresults:
    htmlEl = result.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3.mb-0")

NOTE: The dot in h3.mb-0 indicates a class "mb-0", nothing to do with context, etc.
I prefer CSS selectors over XPath for lots of reasons...

They are faster
They have better browser support
The syntax is shorter, simpler, and easier to read

XPaths have their place...

They are the only locator that can locate elements by contained text
They are the only locator that can perform complicated DOM traversal

I just use CSS selectors whenever possible ... until I have to use an XPath.

Very well explained, thank you! That dot as well is what threw me as it was searching from the previous results

You can iterate through the results and search within each result.
newresults = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//figure[contains(@class, 'card-figure') and contains(@class, 'card-link')]")

for result in newresults:
    h3_tag = result.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//h3[contains(@class, 'mb-0')]")
    print(h3_tag.text)


That won't work... see my answer.
